# What is the rotational velocity of Andromeda?

Tags: resource-recommendations, galaxy-rotation-curve

Can someone give me a reference which gives the [rotation curve of the Andromeda galaxy](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=%22rotation+curve%22&as_epq=andromeda+galaxy) (as well as its radius)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Figs. 6 and 7 of [Wide-field HI mosaic of Messier 31 II. The disk warp, rotation and the dark matter halo](http://arxiv.org/abs/0912.4133).

Starting from the center, rotational velocity increases to a local maximum of about 250 km/s at 14 kpc, decreases somewhat to a local minumum of 220 km/s at 25 kpc, and final rises to a maximum of about 260 km/s by 40 kpc.

See also Fig. 11 of [HI KINEMATICS AND DYNAMICS OF MESSIER 31](http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.3846) which plots rotational curves from four studies.  Basically similar to above, but shows a narrow 350 km/s peak near 2 kpc.